# Android application on auto radio

Tags: android, kivy, can-bus

I create an application android with Python Kivy and i would like to access to the CAN bus to display some data frame. I am using the Volswagen auto radio

Could you please tell me how to read/detect can bus?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Android has not common API for CAN bus, so the manufacturer may have extended Android by a proprietary one. Not sure if this API is documentation is publicly available. But you need more than the brand to check, better use the exact year and model name and best the component info of the radio to search/ask for API documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. the Volswagen Auto Radio use a CAN BOX Decoder but i still don't know how to interact with...